# Python django ImportError: cannot import name (unknown location)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am starting to use Django and was able to get Django Rest Framework working. Now, I am trying out Elasticsearch using https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/0.18/ and also 
following https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/tree/master/examples/simple

I followed the examples, built my project along those lines. I am getting the ImportError when I try to start server, could anyone please review and give me pointers on what I may be missing. I am enclosing some details about my environment for reference.

Thanks

Environment:

```
cmd > pip freeze | find "Django"
django-cors-headers==3.0.2
django-elasticsearch-dsl==0.5.1
django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf==0.18
django-filter==2.1.0
django-nine==0.2.2
djangorestframework==3.9.4
```

### Directory structure

```
demosite 
    demosite
        settings.py [INSTALLED_APPS contains my_rest_app, search_indexes]


my_rest_app   [which works with http://localhost:8000/my_rest_app/]        

search_indexes
    viewsets
        publisher.py  [see below]
    urls.py [see below]
    documents
        publisher.py [see below]




search_indexes/url.py
---------------------
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from search_indexes.viewsets import PublisherDocumentViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]

# **********************************************************
# *********************** Publishers ***********************
# **********************************************************
router.register(
    r'publishers',
    PublisherDocumentViewSet,
    basename='publisherdocument'
)


search_indexes/viewsets/publisher.py
------------------------------------
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import DocumentViewSet

from ..documents import PublisherDocument
from ..serializers import PublisherDocumentSerializer
__all__ = (
    'PublisherDocumentViewSet',
)

class PublisherDocumentViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    """The PublisherDocument view."""

    document = PublisherDocument
    serializer_class = PublisherDocumentSerializer


search_indexes/documents/publisher.py
--------------------------------------
from my_rest_app.models import Publisher

__all__ = ('PublisherDocument',)

INDEX = Index(settings.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NAMES[__name__])

# See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
INDEX.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=1,
    blocks={'read_only_allow_delete': False},
    # read_only_allow_delete=False
)


@INDEX.doc_type
class PublisherDocument(DocType):
    """Publisher Elasticsearch document."""


search_indexes/serializers/publisher.py
---------------------------------------
from ..documents import PublisherDocument

__all__ = (
    'PublisherDocumentSerializer',
    'PublisherDocumentSimpleSerializer',
)


class PublisherDocumentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
and
class PublisherDocumentSimpleSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    """Serializer for Publisher document."""

---------demosite/urls.py
---------demosite/urls.py    
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
#from search_indexes import urls as search_index_urls


urlpatterns = [
    path('my_rest_app/', include('my_rest_app.urls')),

    path('search_indexes/', include('search_indexes.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/my_rest_app/', permanent=True)),

    #path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/search_indexes/', permanent=True)),

]


--------- stack trace -------

  File "C:\apps\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\apps\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\demosite\demosite\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('search_indexes/', include('search_indexes.urls')),
  File "C:\apps\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\apps\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\demosite\search_indexes\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from search_indexes.viewsets import PublisherDocumentViewSet
ImportError: cannot import name 'PublisherDocumentViewSet' from 'search_indexes.viewsets' (unknown location)
```

Comment: It would help if you shared the stacktrace

Comment: Definitely a stacktrace would help, it probably point which file or which import package is throwing the error.

Comment: Added stacktrace

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in the search_indexes/viewsets folder where you import `PublisherDocumentViewSet`? If not, you either need to import it there of change your import statement in urls.py to import the viewset from "search_indexes.viewsets.publisher"

Comment: Thanks @Iain for timely help. I modified search_indexes/urls.py to "from search_indexes.viewsets.publisher import PublisherDocumentViewSet", also changed other imports in same manner and resolved those errors.  Now I can focus on others.

Answer (score 0):

It show the error with the import of PublisherDocumentViewSet, `cannot import name 'PublisherDocumentViewSet' from 'search_indexes.viewsets'`.

Try to change that import in search_indexes/url.py to:

```
from search_indexes.viewsets.publisher.py import PublisherDocumentViewSet
```

or

```
from .viewsets import PublisherDocumentViewSet
```

If the class PublisherDocumentViewSet is defined in the file publisher.py inside the folder viewsets it should fix this error.

Edit: Like @Iain Shelvington  mentioned in the comments, all folders should have a `__init__.py` file inside. If you check the folders in the repository it has a init file. [Github](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/tree/master/examples/simple/search_indexes/viewsets)!